# Protocol relative urls not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-2

This is my base URL:

```
$config['base_url'] = '//'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. 
str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->config->base_url().'index.php/certification/add/'; ?>" 
method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit ='return false;'>
```

This is the result:

```
<form action="//localhost/php/index.php/localhost/php/index.php/certification/add/" 
method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Why does this happen? ([Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http) if you don't know what protocol-relative URLs are.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the prefix http or https protocol to the base_url. So the form action url will start with // as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are getting the base URL correctly. A similar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Answer (score 0):

`$config['base_url']` should not include the file/script path. If you echo it out on it's own, in your case, you should just be getting '//localhost/php/'

What are you trying to do with the additional SCRIPT_NAME stuff?

If I understand correctly you will want to get rid of that part and then use:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->config->base_url('index.php/certification/add/')"
```

(I believe it will work as you have it now after removing the script part from the config, but I suppose this is the 'proper CI way' of doing it)