# Hey, I'm making a contact form, which has to redirect to the same page after submitted

Tags: php, forms

when the url is localhost/school/portfolio/contact.php it works fine, but when I use a get parameter index.php?page=contact it redirects to index.php

The code I use

```
$url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header('Location: '.$url."?sent=yes");
```

What do I have to add?

Comment: What has `OOP` tag got to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

This should help :)

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

Otherwise see my answer on this ["How to get base URL with PHP?" Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php/2820771#2820771) for more help :)

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways to do so.. (choose what suits you..)

1)use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

2)Use `parse_url()` to get `PHP_URL_PATH` and `PHP_URL_QUERY` parts, and redirect to relative path.

But it'll better to store redirect links in session.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old thread, but to help the future visitors to this page it is worth adding a comment about security issues with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

If adding `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to the form action attribute as suggested in the comments above, you are setting yourself up for XSS attack.

One solution is to wrap `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with `htmlentities()` like so:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
```

This is a good read on the topic:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html