# Cant access wp-load.php dynamically

Tags: wordpress

How to have access to wp-load.php ?

I can access it using the following

```
 require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

But I need to find it dynamically so I am using the following but none of them works.

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../wp-load.php');
require_once( dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../wp-load.php");
require_once( ABSPATH.'wp-load.php');
require_once( ABSPATH."wp-load.php");
```

How to have access to localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-load.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code snippets at beginning of file where you require to load wp-load.php

```
/* FindWPConfig - searching for a root of wp */

function FindWPConfig($dirrectory){

global $confroot;


foreach(glob($dirrectory."/*") as $f){



    if (basename($f) == 'wp-config.php' ){

        $confroot = str_replace("\\", "/", dirname($f));

        return true;

    }



    if (is_dir($f)){

        $newdir = dirname(dirname($f));

    }

}



if (isset($newdir) && $newdir != $dirrectory){

    if (FindWPConfig($newdir)){

        return false;

    }   

}

return false;

}



if (!isset($table_prefix)){

global $confroot;

FindWPConfig(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

include_once $confroot."/wp-config.php";

include_once $confroot."/wp-load.php";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same question is [here](http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1670).

Denzel Chia answer was :

> Put the following in the beginning of your file that requires
>   wp-load.php

```
//include wp-config or wp-load.php

$root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));

if (file_exists($root.'/wp-load.php')) {

// WP 2.6

require_once($root.'/wp-load.php');

} else {

// Before 2.6

require_once($root.'/wp-config.php');

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: still does not work the only one that works is the one that I mentioned in the question, is there any alternative ?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure, you may try `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` as described 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php)