# jQuery Ajax JSON object values are NULL

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, null

I'm doing something like this, but getting null values even though the JSON looks like it's coming though formatted correctly. To avoid the returned integer values being wrapped in double quotes I added `absint`. Any idea where I am going wrong? PHP v.5.5.23. Thanks.

class.php

```
public function stats($interval) {          
        global $wpdb;
        $title = $this->title;

        if (is_object($wpdb) && is_a($wpdb, 'wpdb')) {
            $totals = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT * FROM wp_video_stats WHERE vid_title = '$title' AND DATE(updated) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL '$interval' DAY)"); 
         }

         foreach ($totals as $row) {
            $days = absint($row->days);
            $weeks = absint($row->weeks);
            $months = absint($row->months);     
         }

         return array(
           'title'=>$title,
           'days'=>$days,
           'weeks'=>$weeks,
           'months'=>$months
         );  

}

$array = $results->stats(2);

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   header('Content-type: application/json');

   echo json_encode($array);

   exit();
}
```

page.php

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url : '/class.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (data) {         
           console.log(data);  
        },
        error : function () {
           console.log("error");
        }
})
</script>
```

JSON

```
{
    "title":"title_test",
    "days":217,
    "weeks":37,
    "months":3
}
```

console.log

```
Object {title: "title_test", days: null, weeks: null, months: null}
```

Comment: not posting any data in the ajax

Comment: The `$interval` is an argument being passed into the query.

Comment: How many results are you expecting also? If more than one will overwrite variables in loop. Do a dump of `$totals` and see it in your console ... `echo json_encode($totals); exit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. A reference to `wp-load.php` was required in my custom page. Thankfully I found this post  [Cant access wp-load.php dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894946/cant-access-wp-load-php-dynamically) showing a way to include the file which worked for me locally.

```
$root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));

if (file_exists($root.'/wp-load.php')) {
    require_once($root.'/wp-load.php');
} else {
    require_once($root.'/wp-config.php');
}
```

Comment: Mark your answer also for others help.

Comment: Will do Anant I have to wait until tomorrow. Cheers.