# Returning the URL where a script is installed

Tags: php

I need to find out dynamically the base url of a script. Let's say I have installed a script in the folder script, the base url of the script would be
http://www.example.com/script, let's say I place it in the root it has to be http://www.example.com

Is there a way to find this out dynamically?

Using `basename(__DIR__),` or `basename(__FILE__)`, `getcwd()` won't bring me the desired results.

Tried stuff similar to `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`
but this of course always gives back the current page url.

I want to declare a constant called ROOT_URL in my index.php (everything gets loaded by this file), so I can use this constant in any wished project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed with the help of Anthony

Changed his first submitted method a bit :

```
  public static function RealDirname($path)
{
    $path = dirname($path);

    if($path[0] == '\\') //Windows servers tend to mess up [everything]
        $path[0] = '/';

    $lastChar = strlen($path) - 1;
    if($path[$lastChar] != '/')
        $path .= '/';

    return $path;
}

public static function getAbsolutePath()
{
        $path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' :'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $path = $path.self::RealDirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        return substr($path, 0, strpos($path, "index.php"));

}
```

Strips out everything after the index.php and gives me back the root.

Answer (score 1):

I had to cover the same issue a few weeks ago in my MVC implementation.

There you go :

```
public static function RealDirname($path)
{
    $path = dirname($path);

    if($path[0] == '\\') //Windows servers tend to mess up
        $path[0] = '/';

    $lastChar = strlen($path) - 1;
    if($path[$lastChar] != '/')
        $path .= '/';

    return $path;
}

public static function GetAbsolutePath()
{
            global $config;

    if(empty($config["base_path"]))
        $config["base_path"] = self::GetDomainURL();

    return $config["base_path"].(self::RealDirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}

public static function GetDomainURL()
{
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' :'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

Just call getAbsolutePath, and this should return you the whole path with the URL :)

Tried on a page located at :

```
http://localhost:8080/old/test.php
```

GetAbsolutePath returned :

```
http://localhost:8080/old/
```

And GetDomainURL :

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: m8 where is enkelDirname defined :p ?

Comment: Oops, it was a typo, replace it with RealDirname ;)

Comment: Tried it m8, when i define the constant on index.php with your method it returns this: `http://www.domain.com/index.php/user/` when im accessing `http://www.domain.nl/index.php/user/register` It should just return `http://www.domain.com`

Comment: Ok, but when i install the script lets say in a folder called `mvc` , it would still return `http://www.domain.com`, instead of `http://www.domain.com/mvc/`  , thing is i could just add http://www.domain.com/rootfolder or something hard into the code, but i really like this to be dynamicly

Comment: What I have provided now just returns the domain URL, http://domain.com

What was posted before returned dynamically the path of the script, such as:
http://domain.com/mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$script_filename        =       $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];`
You can have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php