# comparing two strings and return matched string

Tags: php

I am trying to get matched parts by comparing

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Like if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returned: `var/www/subdir`

and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` returned `/subdir/index.php/somepage`

so how do i match `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from right

and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` from left and then get the matched part

So that I will get this in output:
`subdir`

Thanks for help

Comment: >I am trying get base url of a application by comparing $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Like if $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returned: var/www/subdir

and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; returned /subdir/index.php/somepage

so how do i match $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] from right and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; from left and return matched.

please can u clear what u exactly wanting...didnot understand

Answer (score 1):

i will advice you to use **`preg_match`**. using it you can get the string before first `/` of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and string after last `'/'` of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and then compare them when a match is found then it will be `subdir` in your case

preg_match documentations ::

1. [**php.net/preg_match**](https://www.php.net/preg_match)
2. [**tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match.htm**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match.htm)
3. [**preg_match EXAMPLES**](http://www.lzone.de/PHP+preg_match+Examples)

for additional information you can also get your root directory  using

`define('DIR_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` in your php file which is kept in your root directory(i.e. index.php,hopefully)... just saying if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the base url, than you are trying the wrong thing. You need to try this

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

This question is already answered here :

[How do I get the base URL with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php)

OR refer to the PHP documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: NO this will not work for me, cuz if I try to get `REQUESTED_URI` from sub directory then this will give current directory.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are trying this ? 

$ss = 'var/www/subdir';
$ps = '/subdir/index.php/';

$ss = end(explode('/', $ss));
$ps = explode('/', $ps);
$ps = $ps[1];


$foo = null;
if($ps == $ss){
  $foo = $ps; 
}
echo $foo;