# How do I dynamically change AJAX url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

```
function updateChatroom() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'../inc/chatroom_update.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response)
        {
            $("#chatUpdate").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

I have this ajax above, which is placed in my includes file under header.php. Now my header.php is included in all my website pages which means the url in my ajax needs to change since my web pages can be in different folders. How do I make the AJAX url dynamic?

In PHP terms, if i wanted to make a link dynamic on my header.php file links. I would set a BASE_URL then put in where the file is located. How do I do this from PHP to AJAX? Thanks in advance!

Comment: from where these dynamic url will be generated ??

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24463585/1059101

Answer (score 1):

Why you not doing this?

```
function updateChatroom(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response)
        {
            $("#chatUpdate").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can call it with any `url`.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic page name:

function updateChatroom(){

```
var url="<?php  echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
$.ajax({
       url:'../inc/'+url,
       type:'POST',
       success:function(response)
       {
       $("#chatUpdate").html(response);
       }
       });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inject the url & post data as parameters.

```
<script>
    function updateChatRoom(url, data) {
        data = data || {};

        //I'd suggest validating this against some list. 
        if(!!url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type:'POST',
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#chatUpdate").html(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Throw
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this function is placed inside *php* file you can use code similar to the one bellow to build URL based on where this page is requested:

```php
<%
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
   $parts = explode('/',$url);
   $dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
    $dir .= $parts[$i] . "/";
  }
%>
function updateChatroom() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $dir . '../inc/chatroom_update.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response)
        {
            $("#chatUpdate").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```