# Resource link redirection

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, phpstorm

I have a css linkage done like following: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/style.css">`, however, for some reason, browser tries to get the file from `localhost//server/template/res/style.css` and fails, because the `server` and `res` both reside on the same level in Document Root. What could be the problem?

Base URL is `localhost//server/template/login.php`

`.htaccess` looks like following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Don't you have any base url for a particular path

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: base url is created to navigate at a particular path...have you created that?

Comment: The base url is `http://localhost/`

Comment: read this for base url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php

Comment: The base url is `localhost//server/template/login.php`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal, so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110989/discussion-between-gaurav-aggarwal-and-nika-gamkrelidze).