# Image doesnt show up in php

Tags: php, html, image, src

In this little snippet of code ,i show how i take the "foto1" column of my database and transfer the value of it to a variable in c# named $foto.
The $foto contains the path of the image corresponding to the product that is showing up. Ive tried to copy and paste the path and ditch out the php part and it works. But when i put it in img src it gives me like the broken image thing.And i cant figure out why it does that.
All help is aprecciated .
Have a nice day :)

```
   <div class="row shop_box-top">
        <?php
        $ligaBD=odbc_connect('basededadospap','','');
        $sql="SELECT * FROM produto WHERE nome_produto LIKE '%ADIDAS%'";
        $resultado=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sql);
        ?>
        <div class="row shop_box-top">

        <?php
        while (odbc_fetch_row($resultado))

    {
        $nome = odbc_result($resultado,2);
        $preco= odbc_result($resultado,4);
        $foto = odbc_result($resultado,9);


        ?>



            <div class="col-md-3 shop_box"><a href="stansmithflatwhite.html">
                <img src="<?php echo $foto; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <span class="new-box">
                    <span class="new-label">Novo</span>
                </span>
                <div class="shop_desc">
                    <h3><a href="stansmithflatwhite.html"><?php echo $nome; ?></a></h3>

                    <span class="actual"><?php echo $preco; ?></span><br>

                </div>

            </a></div>

        <?php }?>
```

Comment: what are you getting in $foto. use var_dump() to check it.

Comment: Is $foto contains logical path or physical path?

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki "images/Cal�ado/Adidas/Homem/Stan Smith/ADIDAS STAN SMITH - RED/ch-adidas-stan-smith-red-5.jpg" and images/Cal�ado/Adidas/Homem/Superstar/NEIGHBORHOOD X ADIDAS CONSORTIUM SUPERSTAR 80 10TH ANNIVERSARY -- BLACKGREY/ch-adidas-nbhd-superstar80-blackgrey-5.jpg

Comment: @RicardoPires If you are using physical path like "c:\xyz\abc.jpg" than it would not work in img tag. It must be logical path like   "http://localhost/xyz/images/abc.jpg"

Comment: @Krunal ohh i understand now , but a physichal path works in just plain html  so why doesnt it work when i put it in a variable in php and then call it?

Comment: You must have used file:// protocol in plain html and you must have accessed html file directly using file:// protocol only. "file://" protocol access file on local system. If you use physical path in your script than it will not work when you host your site. So image path need to be logical path instead of physical path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends of what path contains the $foto var. If is the absolute path, you have to retrive the relative path.
Try also to append an / or an http[s] in front of the path

```
<img src="/<?php echo $foto;?>">
```

So it would be : //path/to/photo

Comment: It doesnt do anything

Comment: i see there is a unicode characters in the name. Is this in some way converted whene printed out?

Comment: Im sorry i didnt understand

Comment: "images/Cal�ado/[..]", is the world "Cal�ado" properly outputed in you html?

Comment: Yes it is properly outputed

Comment: Ive done it by removing the "ç" in the calçado folder , turns out the problem was this word, thank you all so much for your help.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it in your comment, your image paths contain spaces, so a possible solution can be to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before echoing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing full path to img tag like `http://localhost/xyz/images/Cal�ado/Adidas/Homem/Stan Smith/ADIDAS STAN SMITH - RED/ch-adidas-stan-smith-red-5.jpg`.

Replace "localhost/xyz" with your website directory path.

Comment: I think i might be doing this wrong , here goes the code :     <img src="http://localhost/tema/""<?php echo $foto;?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

Comment: You need to use add http:// and quotes need to be close proper. Try this <img src="http://localhost/tema/<?php echo $foto;?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

Comment: It's better to use php variables $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to build base path instead of hard code the value. You can build path like given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php

Comment: im trying the first one still