# Get audio from URL

Tags: php, html, audio

I have this code and I want to get the url from a MySQL database.
But the $urls should contain the https:\...xyfile.mp3 URL from the database.
can anybody help? It may be a syntax error somewhere.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#FED9AF\">\n
    <td width=\"30%\">$artist_name</td>\n
    <td width=\"12%\">$song_name</td>\n
    <td width=\"50%\" align=\"center\">
        <audio controls>
            <source src=\"$url\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">
        </audio>
    </td>\n
    <td width=\"0%\">
        <a href=\"$url\"><img src = '../View/images/download.png'></a>
    </td>\n
    </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Edit: i tried a single audio

```
<audio controls="controls">  
   <source src="http://torejo.atw.hu/Elektronomia%20-%20Limitless.mp3" />   
</audio>
```

and Its isn't not working too... ??

Comment: What exactly are you looking for, do you get any errors.

Comment: @Snm  
Hello , no i don't have. I have a url calledurl varchar(120) utf8mb4_hungarian_ci in database , and i want to be the source of the audio. '<source src=\"$url\'

Comment: you can give it a try by visiting this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php  and check for the function "Fun 'base_url' snippet! "

Comment: @Snm , Tnaks , but i dont thinks so this is my problem  i tried to do it 
 with a singel code , and its isn't working at all.
   <audio controls="controls">  
   <source src="http://torejo.atw.hu/RetroVision_-
  
   _Over_Again_feat_Micah_Martin_NCS_Release[www.MP3Fiber.com].
   mp3" />   
   </audio>

What is the problem with a audio src??