# Relative file paths on localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I am trying to establish a root directory so I can link to other directories on my localhost server. However using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENTROOT']` is showing a file path `"C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp/"` instead of `"localhost/myApp/"`.

Constants haven't worked for me since they are not accessible outside of the file it is declared in?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Better read PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: are you looking for base url?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php