# Get links in slider

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement, while-loop

so I build website with slider in home page and want to have function when they click the slider it will go to link that I input it on database. So here is the code

```
<div id="demo-1" class="imgsl" data-zs-src='[<?php $slno=1; $bannerhome=mysql_query("select * from banneratas where tampil='y' order by nobanner desc");
            while($bn=mysql_fetch_array($bannerhome)){
                $linkbanner=trim($bn['links']);
                if($slno===1){ ?>
                "<?php echo "<a href='$linkbanner' class='linkabsolute' target='_blank'>$_COOKIE[config]dynamic/1366/assets/slide/$bn[gambar]</a>";?>"
                <?php
        else{?>,
         "<?php echo "$_COOKIE[config]dynamic/1366/assets/slide/$bn[gambar]";?>"
        <?php } $slno++;} ?>]'>
```

So I try with `$linkbanner` variable (line 3) to get the link but found error when I call it on line 5

my error will retrieve image source like this
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is your error message

Comment: it will retrieve my image link but only link

Comment: are you need to append `base url`

Comment: yes I need base url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php refer this link

Comment: I'm sorry it still dont answer my question. but thanks for helping

Comment: Your question is not clear u have not added your error message...........

Comment: see my new edit mr.shibon