# Why on Xampp header works but on online webhost doesnt work?

Tags: php, html, sql

is there any mistake?
This fikle is where user goes after his registration, but when i upload my fiels on online webhsot doestn work rightt, it  stacks on the page and shows me a white page, but the registration goes in database, so the problerm is why the header does work?

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $p1= $_POST['password'];
    $password = password_hash($p1,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "id12725183_rentanythingusers";
    $dbuser = "id12725183_root";
    $dbport = 3306;
    $dbpass = "PRi~r99B)Dd1xdKM";

    $dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};port={$dbport}charset=utf8mb4";
    if(empty($fname)  ){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το όνομα είναι υποχρεωτικό!!#logariasmos");
    }else if(empty($lname)){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το επίθετο είναι υποχρεωτικό!!#logariasmos");
    }else if(empty($username)){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το username είναι υποχρεωτικό!!#logariasmos");
    }else if(empty($email)){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το email είναι υποχρεωτικό!!#logariasmos");
    }else if(password_verify("", $password)){
        header("location:User.php?error=Ο κωδικός είναι υποχρεωτικός!!#logariasmos");
    }else if( strlen($username)<6 ){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το username πρέπει να αποτελείτε απο τουλάχιστον 6 ψηφία!!#logariasmos");
    }else if( strlen($p1)<6){
        header("location:User.php?error=Το password πρέπει να αποτελείτε απο τουλάχιστον 6 ψηφία!!#logariasmos");
    }else{
        try{
            $options = [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ];
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO rentanythingregistered(fname, lname, username, email, password) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password)');
            $stmt->execute(["fname"=>$fname, "lname"=>$lname, "username"=>$username, "email"=>$email, "password"=>$password]);
            $_SESSION['ifregistered']=1;
            header('location:User.php?message=Η εγγραφή σας ήταν επιτυχης, μπορείτε να συνδεθείτε στον λογαριασμό σας!');
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            if ($e->errorInfo[1] === 1062) {
                header("location:User.php?error=Το email ή το password, χρησιμοποιείτε ήδη!!#logariasmos");
            }
            else{
                header("location:User.php?error=Connection failed: . $e->getMessage()!#logariasmos");
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will not answer your question but i wanted to give you some feedback about your code.

1. instead of doing

   ```
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   ```

   just use `extract($_POST)`: it will simply create variables named as
   the indexes of the array you pass as argument [read more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)
2. if this script is used for registration, there's no need to use
   password_verify(). in fact you should use it when the user attempts
   to login. and also you're using it improperly, because the first
   parameter must be the non-hashes password, and the second the hashes
   password [read more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)
3. it's not a good practice to add spaces in the url. you should use
   characters like dash to separate words in the url, so it would be
   better to replace this

   ```
   header("location: /example_page.php?error=username cannot be empty")
   ```

   with this

   ```
   header("location: /example_page.php?error=username-cannot-be-empty")
   ```

Comment: Using `extract(...)` would be a security-leak in this case (e.g. can override more variables than we want).

Comment: i didn't notice the warning message in the documentation, can i ask why it would be a security leak?

Comment: Sorry, actually it's always a security leak to convert user-input to variables and hope they do not override anything important.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, i am beginner and you gave me very usefull advices!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, everything works correctly except your redirection-header.

And even that works fine on your local.

The problem might be with the path and/or URL, I mean, while "`User.php`" is fine for your local, but you should not expect it to work everywhere.

1. Try "`/User.php`" instead.
2. Most servers are case-sensitive, ensure `User.php` is exactly the same as the file-name.
3. If nothing else works, try [resolving-address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820771/8740349) like:

```php
function resolveUrl($suffix){
  return sprintf(
    "%s://%s%s/$suffix",
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  );
}


$userUrl = resolveUrl('User.php');
```

And use `$userUrl` variable everywhere else, like:

```
header("location:$userUrl?error=Το όνομα είναι υποχρεωτικό!!#logariasmos");
```

Comment: My friend, i am 100% studpi, the problem was the first line. it was empty, i start my code from second line and it was problem!!!!

Comment: Good that you could fix it, but if nothing in my post was related to solving it, please say that clearly (and I delete my answer).