# PHP session HTTP to HTTPS problem

Tags: php, http, https, session-state

I have a (HTTPS) login.php page which remains HTTPS (ie once user logged in goes to account dashboard). Now the problem is say the user whilst logged on to the secure dashboard clicks onto a non-sensitive page like (HTTP) about-us.php page, the session is not transmitted over HTTP as I have session.cookie_secure=1, meaning the user appears logged out on HTTP pages.

However when the user goes back to dashboard page or any sensitive account page I have been told he should still be logged in (ie from HTTP back to HTTPS)? However  this is not the case and he appears logged out on the HTTPS connection too?

I believe I am missing something which is causing this problem. Here is my code:

This is PHP header file which is called to start session on login.php page:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true); /*avoid session fixation attempt*/

/*Create and check how long session has been started (over 5 mins) regenerate id - avoid session hijack*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();/*time created session, ie from login/contact advertiser/email_confirm only ways for new session to start*/
} 
elseif(time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 300) 
{
    /*session started more than 5 mins(300 secs) ago*/
    session_regenerate_id(true); /*change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID*/
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time(); /*update creation time*/
}

/*Check if user is logged in*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
    $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;/*used to track if user is logged in on pages*/
}

/*if return false browser supports standard ob_start();*/
if(ob_start("ob_gzhandler")){ob_start();}
```

This is PHP header file required on every page to check if session initiated already:

```
session_start(); 

$session_errors=0;/* if>0 user not logged in*/

/*check if session is already initiated*/
if(isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) 
{
    if(time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 300) 
    {
        /*session started more than 5 mins(300 secs) ago*/
        session_regenerate_id(true); /*change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID*/
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time(); /*update creation time*/
    }
}
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])){$session_errors++;}/*user not logged in*/

/*Check if user is logged in*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){$session_errors++;}/*user not logged in*/

if(ob_start("ob_gzhandler")){ob_start();}
```

Also if any use this is the code to turn HTTPS of on non-sensitive pages such as about-us.php

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']!=80)
{
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ":80".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $url");
}
```

My php.ini file cookie settings

```
session.cookie_secure=1
session.cookie_httponly=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.save_path = /tmp
session.save_handler = files
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php

Comment: See the above question (don't follow its suggestions though), when the user moves to http connection, the cookie is not transferred, so when `session_start()` is called, it generates a new session ID, therefore the previous session id is lost.

Comment: @rickchristie, I have read the thread and the only way appears to be to set secure cookie flag to 'Off'. But this is surely insecure as cant my session_id then be sniffed on a HTTP page? I dont want to send session_id through URL massive security flaw.

Comment: yup, it's a huge security hole, that's why I told you not to follow its suggestions :) - I have a solution, posted as an answer below, though it may not be the solution you wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Answered to help people who might stumble across this*

As the the answer at [Session lost when switching from HTTP to HTTPS in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php) has concluded, since you are using `session.cookie_secure = 1` the cookie that contains the session ID is not transferred when the connection switches from HTTPS to HTTP. At HTTP connection, when you `session_start()`, PHP creates a new session id, which replaces the previous session id.

The answer also suggests a solution, pass the session id using query string, which is then picked up by the page. This smells of bad of security flaw. Don't forget the reason why we used HTTPS in the first place!

So the solution I suggest to you is that you *redirect all http request to https counterparts*. Use HTTPS for everything in your site, from css, images, to mundane static html pages. This is actually something that every application that is serious about security does. For example, visiting github page using HTTP will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Sun, 08 May 2011 15:43:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: close
Location: https://github.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.7.67</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember why you used HTTPS in the first place, if you want to be totally secure, use HTTPS for everything.

Detect if the request is HTTPS or not [(See this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-you-are-using-https-without-serverhttps) at bootstrap.

If the request is HTTP, either redirect all requests to HTTPS home page, or you can try parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and redirecting HTTP request to their HTTPS counterpart using `parse_url` and `http_build_url`.

---

**Second Alternative Solution**

If you really really don't want to use HTTPS for everything, then don't `session_start()` on pages that are accessed with HTTP. Secure cookies will be retained when you do this.

---

**Third Alternative Solution**

The other solution is to try and detect the user by IP addresses and user agent. This is not guaranteed to be accurate, so what I suggest is just use HTTPS for everything. Paypal, for example, always use HTTPS even for mundane static pages.

Comment: What do u mean "if you really really don't want to use HTTPS for everything, then don't session_start() on pages that are accessed with HTTP. Secure cookies will be retained when you do this." Do you mean keep the HTTPS on non-sensitive pages but just not use session_start()? So should I use HTTPS for everything only if user is logged in?

Comment: @daza - that statement is part of another solution, updated to make it clearer

Comment: @daza - just use HTTPS for everything, even the non-logged-in user.

Comment: thanks for info, I have decided to use HTTPS on all pages, just seems easiest method rather than having to over complicate things.

Answer (score 9):

The description by @rickchristie is good, but I think there's a better solution that he doesn't suggest. If you don't always want to use HTTPS (which does make sense sometimes; the about_us page doesn't need to be secure), you can follow the advice on the [`session_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) page and use [named sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to continue a previous session. This is simple to use; just include the `session_start` calls with

```
session_name("MySession"); // replace with whatever makes sense
session_start();
```

on all secure pages.