# session Not storing when switching from HTTP to HTTPS in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am changing my site http to https, then in my server sessions not working.
By this problem we are not loading dashboard after login please send me solutions.

Thank you all.

Comment: is your session cookie set to use https?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session HTTP to HTTPS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921545/php-session-http-to-https-problem)

Comment: How did this question get 5 favourites?