# Check if current request is secure (ssl)

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 2, I want to check if the current request is secure (SSL) or not, and I know that we can do that with pure php such as checking the $_SERVER['https']. However, I wonder if there is any Symfony method/helper that already helps us to determine that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) has [isSecure](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_isSecure) method. You can use it in your **controller** in the following way:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isSecure()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my case this function was not working correctly, so I used the one described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-you-are-using-https-without-serverhttps