# How to know request coming from https server in php?

Tags: php, curl

Suppose, I have two website first.com and second.com.
I am making a curl request from first.com by the curl. Is it, possible to know that it,s https request or http request on server second.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Find Out If You are Using HTTPS Without $\_SERVER\['HTTPS'\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-you-are-using-https-without-serverhttps)

Comment: If i user $_SERVER variable, it,s show the status current server second.com. But i want to know the status of first.com while a curl request coming from first.com and hit second.com. I want know that, Is request coming from secure server at second.com

Comment: As i posted in my answer, the $_SERVER["HTTPS"] shows whether the server who send the request was using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]` if its 80, then its a simple request, if 443 or secure protocol's port then its https.

And maybe `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort = On` has to set on Apache2.

> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I would't trust the port, it's configurationable.

Comment: But u wont set secure protocol to 80 :P And configure by the script owner in good case. So it will be synced.

Comment: No, but you could use port 993, 443, etc etc, so'll the answer i gave will tell you :) $_SERVER["https"]

Answer (score 1):

From the manual, it seems that $_SERVER contains an indication whether this is HTTP or not.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> 'HTTPS'
>   Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>   Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

So checking $_SERVER["HTTPS"] should be okay, i dont have any idea whether this can be trusted or not.

Comment: I want to know the status, when request coming on server second.com, it,s coming from secure server or not

Comment: "'HTTPS' Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol", so if the request is from a server running HTTPS, it the value would be set to a non-empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Chauhan,

it's possible via PHP Global variable. you have uses $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable in second.com.
it will return http request url.

Learn more for php global variable visit http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php