# Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in [...]

Tags: php

I have a breadcrumb script and its displaying an error:

"Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in ... on line ..."

The code line is:

```
$base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-youre-using-https-without-serverhttps

Comment: Well was the script queried through HTTPS? if not then https wouldn't be defined.

Answer (score 2):

Check for the existence of the `HTTPS` key first using [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
$base = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

In this particular case you only need to check existence so it would be safe to simplify it to:

```
$base = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious low quality question which there are well known dupes for.