# can i move site from http to https due to mixed content warning

Tags: php, curl, https, mixed-content

I am facing **Mixed content** warning when i am trying to load files from http to https.

But now i am planning to move my site from http to https.

I need to know whether files will be loaded from

```
https -> https
https > http
```

without any issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Change your links and remove the scheme so for example `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` becomes `//example.com` or you could go down the route of detecting it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-youre-using-https-without-serverhttps

Comment: i have tried that, with this problem remain if i more my site to https ?

Comment: does all files loaded easily from https to http ?

Comment: no it won't it will handle both, though you should be able to check which resource is causing the issue and fix that.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you publish all content via https, then why should you get a mixed content issue? That will only happen for references to http urls from pages loaded via https.

Comment: that is what i want to know, actually i created script which fetches files from https and loaded on http, which shows mixed content, but i was thinking if i move my site(script) to https, then files will be loaded easily on both https and http, right ?

Comment: is the page public facing so we can see it?

Comment: why do you need to do this? Doesn't the scripts, sources, or other files still load? They should! It's also possible that your files actually point to http or https with external paths from your files if there scripts of any kind! It might be possible but I don't know for sure! Try investigating which files and what parts of files by using the JavaScript console! Also just change all files to http or https or do a redirect using .htaccess or other methods

Comment: all popup contents are coming from http, but when i run this on https, it shows mixed content warning.

Comment: to clarify, is the **https** page public facing so we can see the **error**?

Answer (score 0):

Short version: YES, you will still face mixed content if the below cases are not treated, even after migration to https.

If you're migrating your website from http to https these are the two cases you need to consider that would still result in mixed content warning :

- Your website is on https but you still have absolute paths starting with http://  in the source code ; you need to change them in the code

  - Your website contains URLs to external resources ( again absolute urls ) and they start with http:// ;  in this case you need to check if the 3rd party serves content on https then change the URL accordingly; if not, you could just remove the http:// urls to get rid of the warning ( or make a copy of the resources locally and serve them on https )

Answer (score -1):

Just add the  2 script versions one with http in from and one with https just make sure the https files support https or it won't work still! Or if there on your system just add /file path and if not you can try to have files be //external file path don't add https or http in them!

Comment: You can also use .htaccess and redirect http to https!

Comment: i have tried with files // without http or https, but right now i am in mood to move site to https, i just need to know whether files be loaded from https to http without any problem or it will again show mixed content warning like if we use https to http ?

Comment: I'm afraid that may be impossible! However why do you need to do this? Doesn't the scripts, sources, or other files still load? They should! It's also possible that your files actually point to http or https with external paths from your files if there scripts of any kind! It might be possible but I don't know for sure! Try investigating which files and what parts of files by using the JavaScript console!