# PHP Notice: Undefined index Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to execute WordPress cron but getting an error.
Command Executed:
`/usr/bin/php7.1-sp /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/wp-cron.php`

Errors:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTPS in
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/wp-config.php
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public/wp-config.php

My wp-config file:

```
define('SP_REQUEST_URL', ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_SITEURL', SP_REQUEST_URL);
define('WP_HOME', SP_REQUEST_URL);
```

I have tried searching and replacing code but it doesn't work. the only solution I got is to manually define the URL.

Comment: Although not completely full proof might suffice for your needs - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886224/903324

Answer (score 0):

Can you define a new value for the home url.
Something line below

```
define('SP_REQUEST_URL', ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('SP_REQUEST_URL_HOME', ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_SITEURL', SP_REQUEST_URL);
define('WP_HOME', SP_REQUEST_URL_HOME);
```

Thanks,
Raghava

Comment: Format your code