# Get protocol of request in boost/beast

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I'm having trouble to get the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) of a request in boost beast webserver.

I can get the host using:

```
req[http::field::host]
```

but no such luck with the protocol.

```
req[http::field::protocol]
```

is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no http::field for HTTPS.

For using HTTPS basically you are doing following (example):

1.Create io_context and ssl_context

```
boost::asio::io_context ioc;
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client)
```

2.create ssl stream from io_context and ssl::context

```
boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream> stream(ioc, ctx)
```

3.create tcp connection using lowest_layer

```
beast::get_lowest_layer(stream).connect(...endpoints iterator from query resolver..)
```

4.do the ssl handshake

```
stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
```

5.now you can make requests writing to stream as usual:

```
 http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, target, version};
 req.set(http::field::host, host);
 req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

// Send the HTTP request to the remote host
 http::write(stream, req);
```

Check the official boost beast [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/client/).

Comment: I’m writing a server not a client. The server is http behind a nginx proxy. I need to find out it the client browser connects using https or http. 
Something like $server[SERVER_PROTOCOL] in PHP.

Comment: YOU (server) decide which protocol you provide on each port. Normally 80=HTTP, 443=HTTPS. If the client connects on 443 in this example, that means HTTPS -> SSL handshake has to be maked. So I dont quite get your question, sorry. In the question you asked about makeing HTTP request -> it's the clientside, not server.

Comment: Seems to be misunderstanding here. I'm pretty sure the question is not Beast related:  we're talking about which headers we can use to figure out which protocol is being used. OP said it: he's behind a nginx proxy. It's very possible that connections to the Beast server are done with HTTP, _even_ when the client uses HTTPS. I think he doesn't care what protocol is used for the Beast connection: what he wants to know is the protocol being used by the connection between the client and nginx. There are headers for that, like HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you are behind a nginx server, Beast cannot solve your problem. But the additional headers that nginx will send to your server will.

You may rely on the [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) headers. Here's what I came up with by following [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076965/626921) to a similar question:

```cpp
using namespace boost::beast;
using namespace std;

string find_scheme(const http::request<http::string_body>& request)
{
  http::request<http::string_body>::const_iterator header;

  header = request.find("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO");                                                                    
  if (header != request.end())                                                                                        
    return header->value().data();                                                                                    
  else
  { 
    header = request.find("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL");                                                                    
    if (header != request.end())
      return header->value() == "on" ? "https" : "http";                                                              
  }     
  return "http";
}
```