# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns PHP file not URL

Tags: php, request, uri

Below are the relevant lines of code:

**update.js**

```
$('#tablePlaceholder').load('updateTable.php');
```

**updateTable.php**

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Normally `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the URL, however in this case, the URI at the moment of the request is technically the PHP file, so what is returned is `updateTable.php` instead of the actual URL. Is there an alternate command I can use to get the URL instead of URI? I have resorted to storing the URL in a session/global variable to retain access to the actual URL in the PHP file, but it seems there must be a better way, though I have not found it. Any tips would be most welcome!

I was looking at the documentation for the jQuery `load()` command:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

It looks like I might be able to pass the URL as a string via the data argument?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual URL" exactly, the HTML file where this all takes place?

Comment: By actual URL, I mean the URL in the address bar.

Comment: Right. The Ajax call is a separate request, so that is by design; however, you should be able to get the calling page by looking at `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is supposed to give path of current script relative to root and not the full url. If you want to get full url path, take a look at the same question on stackoverflow with the solution also being there

[Getting the full URL of the current page (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236873/getting-the-full-url-of-the-current-page-php)

Comment: Wow, that is quite elaborate. In my situation the URL in the address bar will always be something basic like PageName.html (no question marks, additional slashes, ports, ampersands... simply a filename and then the .html extension). I don't suppose there is something more basic?

Comment: @KenBoone that is the way to do it. It takes care of whether http or https is being used. Also taking care of port number as well

Comment: @KenBoone If that did solve your question, can you accept the answer?