# Redirecting all HTTPS to HTTP except two pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried some help from other topics on this site but I faced the redirect loop error.

My current htaccess code:-

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php\?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above is not related to this question but to get a proper help from you, I have included it.

Now I want to redirect all https urls to http except two /login/ and /register/

How can I ensuring to use the minimum conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are wedded to using .htaccess, you could at the top of the pages you want to go to http check with PHP and use a header location to send them to http.

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$rest_of_path);
```

There is some good info here on how to construct the whole url so they go to the same page.
[Getting the full URL of the current page (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236873/getting-the-full-url-of-the-current-page-php)