# PHP if (Logged In) then (Load Page) else (redirect to login)?

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I'm trying to understand how to write PHP code to only allow logged-in visitors to access a directory/folder. I already have the `.htaccess` rule to load a PHP doc when visiting the url, and it redirects to the login page like I want. But I'm trying to understand the PHP to load the url content when the user is logged in.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
/* Protect directory files with login. */

 /* Load WordPress heading */
require_once('wp-load.php');
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
wp_cookie_constants();


/* If user is logged-in else redirect to login */
is_user_logged_in() ||  auth_redirect();
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236873/getting-the-full-url-of-the-current-page-php) to get the current page url using this code:

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
```

But how do I write an expression to load the page if the user is logged in?

---

And for those who want to know the `.htaccess` rule I'm using to load the login-check.php file is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*protected/.*
RewriteRule ^protected/(.*)$ login-check.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sometimes Google is a really good helper ;) http://www.php-login.net/

Comment: The best way is to use PHP Session. On the WWW are thousends of sites about PHP Login Scripts.

Comment: If I hadn't searched for hours online to no avail, I wouldn't be posting here asking the question. Thank you for no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must save the information that the user is logged in a $_SESSION so you can validade it everytime you load a page.

What you need is something like this:

When your user is loggin in you should do this:

> if($user == 'user' && $pass =='password'){
>       $_SESSION['auth']['user'] = $user;
>       $_SESSION['auth']['logged'] = true; }

Create a function to check if the user is logged in:

> function checkLoggedUser($user) {
>       if ($_SESSION['auth']['user'] != $user || $_SESSION['auth']['logged'] != true)
>     header('location:redirectpage.php');
>       echo 'page content here.'; }

at the start of every 'protected' PHP file call the function:

> checkLoggedUser($_SESSION['auth']['user']);

Remember this is an example, avoid using logged==true at all costs for security reasons.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I greatly appreciate it! I will check out your suggested code.