# Codeigniter: Check and force one page to https://

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want most of my site to be http:// but for a single checkout page to be https://

How can I check and switch the user to https:// so there's no chance they can use it with http://?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106313/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can force SSL for specific URLs using .htaccess rules. In this example, if someone visits any of the register/payment directories, they will be redirected to the https:// URL.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond $1 ^(register/payment|login)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond $1 !^(register/payment|images|css|javascript|login)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can change this according to your needs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way tested and works fine for me

Add this code in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^checkout ? https://myproject.localhost/my_checkout_url [R,L]
```

Hope it works fine for you also