# Using https in php5

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, https

**QUESTION**:
 How to use https in registration/login(any other) php page?
 pseudo code:

```
is it https?
yes continue
no redirect same page via https
```

**Background:**
I wanna make secure registration and login form. 
 1. I wanna go throught all steps to detect if I'm not missing something.
 2. I wanna ask especialy how to use https to protect the passwords on the way to server.

- **add 1.** steps:   a. User click on link registration/login => check if
  the registration/page uses https - if not   redirct and use https
  (this I do SOMEHOW BUT DON'T KNOW HOW - the second part of question) 
  b. so now I'm connected to the registration/login page via https,
  user set the passwords into imput    fieldt which will be obviously
  set to input type password(and obviously use post method), then he
  press submit button - cause I use post + https the data should be
  pass secure to the server.   c. now the registration/login script is
  passed, and its redirected to the handle page it could be    same php
  page - I thing I should still use https.   d. now I encript the
  passwords via sha256 something like sha256(sha256(password)+salt),
  make connection to database using prepared statement to prevent sql
  injection   e. if the input data is ok registration is done (some
  mail could be sent but its another problem,   don't need to solve it
  here), if its is login and the passwords fits I put some data to
  session -    info about user like id + rights, QUESTION IS: should I
  still use https for members section?   I think it's not important,
  unless I wanna change password (I will use https again for change
  password form).
- **add 2.** HTTPS CONNECTION CHECK    user click link to the login/registration page, I should do something like:

  IS it HTTPS? YES => CONTINUE, NO => REDIRECT SAME PAGE VIA HTTPS    I    know there is some variable or something which tells me if its https,    but I don't know how to 
          write it in php5(this one or two lines). So the question is how to do point 2(HTTPS connection CHECK)?

Comment: Instead of two passes of SHA-256, use [CRYPT_BLOWFISH](http://php.net/manual/function.crypt.php). SHA is for fast hashing of large data blocks and therefore not suited for password encryption.

Comment: Well I'll check this part. But my main poit was that https.

Comment: Why don't you use HTTPS on all pages?

Comment: Cause its to much not important overhead?

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but if you're attempting to implement your own authentication system (which I would strongly counsel you against doing) then you should certainly read [The definitive guide to form based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477578).

Comment: @eggyal thx, I have to do it :P it seems rly helpful, thx so + for the advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106313/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if the request has been made through HTTPS, check [$_SERVER['HTTPS']](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
$https = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off';
```

Comment: Well this is exactly I needed :)