# can i redirect to https using ng-view on a specific route?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I'm working on an angular 1.5.0-rc0 project.

I'm using angular-route with ng-view with the following configuration:

```
  app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController',
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/cocktail/:cocktail_name', {
            templateUrl: 'views/cocktail.html',
            controller: 'CocktailController',
        }).
        when('/add-drink',{
            templateUrl: 'views/add-drink.html',
            controller: 'AddDrinkController',
        }).
        when('/add-cocktail',{
            templateUrl: 'views/add-cocktail.html',
            controller: 'AddCocktailController',
            controllerAs: 'addCocktail'
        }).
        when('/admin-drinks',{
            templateUrl: 'views/admin-drinks.html',
            controller: 'AdminDrinksController',
            controllerAs: 'adminDrinks'
        }).
        when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'login'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

I want to check if users are browsing using https or http. and in case they browse `/login` using http I want to redirect them to https.

how can i do that ?

Comment: If you are creating a Single Page Application, you may as well  just make it all https, rather than only trying to redirect them if they go to /login - if you are only using Angular routing, once they have logged in they will remain on https anyway. Better to do this server-side as @GadgetBlaster says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it server side before the site loads your JS. I have done this in an angular app in the past and it is more secure to do it in PHP or Apache. Here is a PHP example:  [Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106313/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-php)