# Auto load the website to Subfolder with HTTPS in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I just installed SSL certificate on the server.

Current URL: www.example.com

Current working htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
```

it is redirecting to public/index.php.

but problem is when I am adding HTTPS code in htaccess then this public/index.php is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R]
```

When I am removing public redirection part then HTTPS is working but not pointing to public/index.php.

How can I combine these rules so it will redirect to public/index.php with https url.

PS: public/htaccess

```
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Please help!

Thank You

Comment: Is it necessary to redirect to the HTTPS version using .htaccess?

Comment: If you have any other way then please ! may it will help

Comment: Are you using a framework? or is there any PHP file that is included in all other files?

Comment: Not I am using Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to redirect to your HTTPS website:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off"){
    $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

From: [Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106313/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-php)

However, this piece of code needs to be included on every page, or include it in a PHP file that is included in all other files.

Comment: I'll remove the .htaccess part I'm not an "expert" in using the .htaccess, I hope one of the folks can post an answer with .htaccess method or simply update my answer.