# i need redirect http://site name and www.sitename.com, but it redirects to https://www

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi how can I redirect `toptangiy.com` and `www.toptangiy.com` redirect to https://www.toptangiy.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toptangiy.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.toptangiy.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This is my htaccess after this codes site write err too many redirects

Comment: Your first condition doesn't include www in the redirect.

Comment: I would suggest that you do a search on the subject before posting. This is a common question with _many_ examples here on SO alone.Try: _"apache redirect to https"_. I'm quite sure you will find some that fits your case more or less exactly. If not, take one that works and modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: i am need only correct codes for redirecting  [link](https://toptangiy.com)

Comment: this will help in redirecting all traffic to https `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Follow the following link:
[Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5106355/6048160)

Comment: You can follow [http to https through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

If the task is enforce https and www for a domain, it's a very common task, and there's lots of answers on StackOverflow for it. But as far as the way I'd write this for your case, I'd use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Enforce https for toptangiy.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.toptangiy.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.toptangiy.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Enforce www for toptangiy.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toptangiy.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.toptangiy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i remove that and same problem

Comment: i can write you my admin panel password you can control that ?

Comment: @JrAa Made an adjustment. Due to a permanent 301 redirect being used, browsers will cache previous redirects.Try testing on http://websniffer.cc/

Comment: @7060965 That's simply incorrect. The rewrite rule only matches the `/` and does not include the domain. When testing on htaccess.madewithlove.be you need to include the scheme in the request url you're testing on as noted on the site.

Comment: @JrAa don't share cpanel user name and password in comments. if you trust some one then share on email instead of comments or public platform

Comment: this is my htaccess 


my domain redirecting to `http://site name`  to 

    https://www.sitename

only i need toptangiy.com and www.toptangiy.com redirect too `https://www.toptangiy.com`

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>    this is correct only http://www.toptangiy.com not redirect too https://www.toptangiy.com

Comment: Bilal Ahmed thank you )

Comment: @JrAa See updated post. Test using http://websniffer.cc/

Comment: HTTP Request Header
Connect to 188.93.212.115 on port 443 ... ok

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WebSniffer/1.0 (+http://websniffer.cc/)
Host: www.toptangiy.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://websniffer.cc/

HTTP Response Header
Name Value
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 06:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 22398
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36

Comment: @JrAa nginx? Might verify your setup is properly funneling to apache so it can read .htaccess files. If it's straight nginx, it won't read .htaccess files (apache only). Also might need to clear your cache due to 301 redirects being used and test in incognito. Hence my reason for suggesting websniffer.cc

Comment: i clerar cache no worked axax

Comment: @JrAa I don't believe you're using the code in my post... Please test on http://websniffer.cc/ The behavior I currently see for whatever setup you have on your domain is both:
`https://toptangiy.com/` and `http://toptangiy.com/` are permanently redirecting to `https://www.toptangiy.com/`
But `http://www.toptangiy.com/` (has www but no https ) is NOT redirecting...
The .htaccess code in my post should redirect this. See for yourself on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
When you see the proper behavior on http://websniffer.cc/ then only attempt to clear your cache.

Comment: I can write you my password and login do you can help me give me your email adres

Comment: i write to your e-mail adres

Comment: Ultimater thank you so much)