# Why do some PHP installations have $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] and others not?

Tags: php, apache2

I run two Apache 2 servers. One has PHP5.2 and the other has PHP5.3. Is there a reason why on the 5.3 machine has `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']`?

Where does this variable come from? It is clearly something that is coming through from the Apache environment and it is not documented in the PHP manual. It is however a handy shortcut over a combination of `['HTTPS']`, `['SERVER_NAME']` and `['REQUEST_URI']`.

I have tried looking through configuration files, searching SO and the web.

Comment: I assume you mean "and the other has 5.3"? as for your question, sorry but I'm not sure. longshot but have you had a look round the apache2 docs? AFAIK alot of what is available in the $_SERVER[] global is determined by the server itself. odd that the manual doesn't document it... 5.3 has been out for a while now hasn't it?

Comment: Thanks I have fixed that version number!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a [post on WebHostingTalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=559266&postcount=3) it comes from mod_rewrite:

> Add
>
> `RewriteEngine On`
>
> To the virtual host in your httpd.conf file that you want to turn this
>   on for and then restart apache.

Comment: No that didn't do the trick. The rewrite engine is on on my system and my Webpage is inside a virtual host. But nonetheless it didn't work.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to set it in the site's http config file.

Answer (score 4):

I moved to CentOS 7 with Plesk12, PHP 5.6.6 and rewrite on etc.
SCRIPT_URI has not been there.
And because it is so nice to use in some situations I wrote this workaround:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'])){
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $pos = strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'],'/');
    if($pos!==false) {
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'], 0, $pos+1);
    }
}
```

As I am not a total expert, please review this code to your specific application before plugging it in. On my system it seems to work perfectly. I just put it in the Head-Area of my index.php and others.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` is only available if you're running PHP as a CGI. I suppose that must be the difference in your two PHP installations.

Comment: My server has SCRIPT_URI set, but php_sapi_name() reports apache2handler. (mod_php with PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.4 on Fedora 18)

Comment: This isn't true for me: I'm using PHP as mod_php and it has SCRIPT_URI defined.