# Smarty code for If/Then statement based on URL value

Tags: php, smarty

the URL is like: **myweb.com/home/8-sticker-papdie.html**

I use:

```
{if $smarty.server.SCRIPT_URI|strstr:"home"}
Display message "YES"
{else}
None
{/if}
```

When I run it I can only see "None".

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me, in case someone else has same problem: {if strstr($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, 'home') !== false} Display message "YES" {else} None {/if}

Comment: As you have problably already found out, `SCRIPT_URI` variable is no longer supported by PHP (no trace of it in [docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) and is not working on certain range of servers or hosts -- look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/717874/1469208) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8398391/1469208).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
{if strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'home') !== false}
    Display message "YES"
{else}
    None
{/if}
```

Comment: i tried this... No luck, i see "None". Also tried {if strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '/home/') !== false} Also no results

Comment: Try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Comment: Not working. I am ussing prestashop 1.6. & i test this code inside the footer.tpl, if this info can help.

Comment: Thank you for your try. I found the solution. Dont know if its only for PRESTASHOP or for any smarty, but $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI did the trick

Comment: {if strstr($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, 'home') !== false}
    Display message "YES"
{else}
    None
{/if}

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need URL/domain name

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will help you :**

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strstr:"home"}
Display message "YES"
{else}
None
{/if}
```