# breaking into SESSION variable

Tags: php, security, session

In every PHP file in my project I am using the following code so that nobody can get into the website without logging in:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['userid']!="myuserid"){
        header("Location: Adminlogon.php");
    }
?>
```

Note that I need only one user id, the user id and password is shared among a group of people.

Is this code safe? Can I do better?

Comment: Put `exit()` after you send your redirect header.

Comment: It's not bullet-proof (few things are), but it will do well enough for a simple deterrent.

Comment: If you're looking for security then I'm not sure a shared id/password is a great way to go, unless you're enforcing only one sign-on at a time (i.e. if someone else tries to sign on you deny it as long as there's a session active).  If not then what's to stop people for sharing the id/password with other (unauthorized) users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not safe, because actually it does not prevent from each script being executed - which is what you actually want to prevent.

To prevent execution if the session is not set correctly, you need to leave the file, for example with the return statement:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['userid'] != "myuserid")
    {
        header("Location: Adminlogon.php");
        return; ### leave this script/include
    }
?>
```

Instead of `return` you can also use the `exit` or `die` statement for rudimentary scripts.

Comment: If your program has any registered shutdown functions or object destructors, they will still run even after the exit statement.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine:  And if you've got a serialized payload inside the session, it will exploit the application as well.

Answer (score 0):

That will be safe, but cookie and session can be easily "hijacked" in LAN when you are using plain HTTP. So force your application server to use HTTPS

Comment: How do I force the application server to use HTTPS?

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85816/how-can-i-force-users-to-access-my-page-over-https-instead-of-http