# Loop in redirect php

Tags: redirect, ssl, dns

I'm trying to redirect my domain http://www.domain.com to other domain with ssl https://www.domain2.com

I use this code in the index.php:

```
<?php header("Location: https://www.domain2.com"); ?>
```

And I get this error: "This web page has a redirect loop".
What can be the problem ?. I also try redirecting to javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's an infinite loop. You should only redirect if it's not HTTPS. Put an `IF` statement in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force users to access my page over HTTPS instead of HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85816/how-can-i-force-users-to-access-my-page-over-https-instead-of-http)

Answer (score -1):

Clearing your cookies is another prudent action.