# I purchased an SSL certificate for my website through godaddy. How do I force my website to always load https instead of http?

Tags: ssl, https

this is my first website. I got the SSL certificate so I could host an app I made that uses the navigator method for location services. However my site does not naturally load on https unless I specifically type the s in place. How do I make it always load securely?

Edit: solved
here is the link I used to solve this issue using godaddy hosting

[Link to godaddy help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120)

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85816/how-can-i-force-users-to-access-my-page-over-https-instead-of-http. "rewrite" is one way but the best solution IMO will be HSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force all web traffic to use HTTPS insert the following condition in your root folder's `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.your-website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: damn I don't seem to have that file :/

Comment: Just create one in your root directory

Comment: is root directory public_html?

Comment: sorry I am very new to this. there isn't much information for these stupid questions online because apparently I'm the only one who doesn't get it naturally

Comment: it says it already exists but it's not showing up and doesn't appear when I search all my folders for it. thanks for trying

Comment: Its a hidden file. Do you have any options to show all files in you UI, maybe hidden files are not being shown now?

Comment: no I looked everywhere. no options to view hidden files. how annoying

Comment: well I gave you credit because your solution helped give me a term to search "redirect"

here is the link I used to solve this issue for godaddy

https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120