# Enforce SSL for Wordpress site on App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, ssl

Successfully installed a certificate for my wordpress website on
   www.example.com, and the site is running on Google App Engine.

However when I type:

example.com or www.example.com it doesn't instantly change over to https://www.example.com.

The site is only 'secure' if explicitly typing in the https part.

I made the following change to my wp-config file explicitly type 'https://':

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

But this hasn't help enforce SSL no matter what address the user types into the browser as desired.

Is this code correct? or is there another/better way to achieve this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85816/how-can-i-force-users-to-access-my-page-over-https-instead-of-http

Comment: Did you add `secure: always` to your handlers in the `app.yaml` file?

Comment: I'll try this. I hadn't seen this handler before.